# Decoding GPS coordinates in image properties

Tags: iphone, ios, gps, metadata, jpeg

Some photo images contain GPS metadata and I would like to understand the following metadata properties of the GPS location which the images taken from an iPhone would produce.

Latitude: 1;23;30.7, Longtitude: 103;54;30

The above are the sample GPS metadata I found from a JPEG image taken from an iPhone. Does anyone know how to decode it's meanings ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Degrees:minutes:seconds of arc.

To convert to decimal degrees:

```
degrees + minutes/60.0 + seconds/3600.0
```